# Place hub classes of signalR in separate folder in asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I followed a signalR tutorial at

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-1x/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

it works just fine with all of the hubs i created.
but problem occurs, when i try to separate the hub class in to a separate folder.

Let's say I want to place all my Hub class in to a root Hubs Folder.

I tried with changeing,

from src="/signalr/hubs"
to src="/hubs"
at the client end and

and from
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();

to
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs("~/Hubs", new HubConfiguration());
at the server end

As my hubs are in root Hubs folder

How should I do it?

Comment: Which SignalR version are you using? I believe the MapHubs-method is obsolete in version 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the signalr connection url to a custom path. The hub proxy classes generation path will be the "/hubs" subfolder from the signalr connection url specified (which is "/signalr" by default), as described in http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#dynamicproxy.